# Custom CSS for full post vs. excerpt (Content Options)

Tags: customization, css, excerpt, content

Is there a way activate "Full Post" via Custom CSS or any other way?

Right now I am stuck with Excerpts on the Homepage and my Theme Customizer > is missing Content Options

Here below is what my theme (named Blog Writing) should provide but does not :/

Or could this be used? https://gist.github.com/thefuxia/2973189

Thank you

[image]

Comment: The link you provided transforms full content into an excerpt, so that's backwards from what it sounds like you're wanting. :)

Comment: I know @WebElaine :). I've tried to invert /excerpt/content/ everywhere in the file, but it does not work on my child theme of `blog writing`, whose parent is theme `bloge`

Answer (score 0):

CSS can only change things visually. So, it can hide what's already there, but it can't make more text appear than what is actually being output to the page.

For this type of change, it's typically best to create a child theme - which basically just means you create a new folder in `/wp-content/themes/` and add a `style.css` file with a few comments at the top telling WP this is a child of whatever parent theme you're using. From there, you copy only the file(s) that need changes into your child theme folder and change them there. That way you can keep the parent theme updated and it won't overwrite your tweaks.

Themes vary in how many files they have and where they store information, but homepage code is often found in `front-page.php` or `home.php`. You're looking for some variation of `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` which you should be able to just change to `<?php the_content(); ?>` - though depending on the theme, you might also have to adjust some CSS to have this display appropriately.

Comment: Thks a lot @WebElaine.   I've only found `the_excerpt` occurences in a sub folder named `template_parts` of theme `blog writing` (a child of `bloge`) ...  I've modifed `content.php` and it workds but it adds some garbage on the homepage...

Comment: here is the result https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OQ1DSnefw0uwm3hpd_2io5TU_QLLq-l1/view?usp=sharing
and here are the possible files to edit https://drive.google.com/file/d/15tFC83jwFDVYSo0jnZOz7hzTNh9iefYO/view?usp=sharing
thank you for any help!